# Cannot put standard value in HTML option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I want to give a standard value to a option list in HTML. Though this list is defined in another JS file and i cannot give it the value as it just gives the standard.

The file where it is defined:

```
$(function(){
var $select = $(".1-100");
for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
    $select.append($('<option></option>').html(i))
}
});
```

with HTML

```
<strong>Age:</strong><span>
    <select id="age" class="1-100"></select>
    </span>
```

With this im trying to set the value as folloing:

```
document.getElementById("age").value = age;
```

But this only gives the standard "1" even if age is higher than this.

Comment: Don't you mean `$select.append($('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'))` ?

Comment: As you are using jQuery use __.val()__ like `$("#age").val(age)`

Answer (score 0):

class name should start with alphabate

```
$(function(){
var select = $(".a1_100");
for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
    select.append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>')
}
});

<strong>Age:</strong><span>
    <select id="age" class="a1_100"></select>
    </span>
```

Comment: I have used this, but it won't solve the problem. It will still state 1. Even with the jquery as said by @Satpal